# Measure which is set to 0 for all but the first date

Tags: powerbi, dax

I want to define a measure which returns the sum of a certain column **only** for the first date in the range, otherwise it should return the value 0. Idea is that I want to use this measure as a baseline in a waterfall chart which I will add to the delta values.

### Example Data

| Date | Backlog |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.2021 | 10 |
| 1.1.2021 | 12 |
| 2.1.2021 | 11 |
| 2.1.2021 | 13 |
| 3.1.2021 | 14 |
| 3.1.2021 | 15 |

### Expected Result

| Date | Backlog |
| --- | --- |
| 1.1.2021 | 22 |
| 2.1.2021 | 0 |
| 3.1.2021 | 0 |

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define measure like this:

```
Measure = 
var minDate = MINX(ALLSELECTED('Table'), 'Table'[Date])
return IF(MAX('Table'[Date]) = minDate, SUM('Table'[Backlog]), 0)
```

Where you will get the minimum date in the current filter context and then sum up the values up to this date, or 0 for the dates after.

[image]

If you want to use the minimum date available, regardless of the current filter, replace [ALLSELECTED](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/allselected-function-dax) with [ALL](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/all-function-dax) in the code above.